# Java HashMap - How to Create third parameters to store my user amount

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm learning how to use a hashmap. I am trying to build an ATM program that can store the user's initial amount so that when I want to deposit or withdraw or check my balance, I can do it. Below is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("123456789", "123456");
        map.put("987654321", "654321");

        boolean valid = false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!valid) {
            System.out.println("Enter Your Card Number");
            String card = in.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Your Pin Number");
            String pin = in.next();
            String actualPin = map.get(card);
            valid = pin.equals(actualPin);
            if (!valid) {
                System.out.println("Wrong Card Number or Pin Number");
                System.out.println("Try Again");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Congratulations on logging in");
                Scanner question = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Press 1 to Withdraw");
                System.out.println("Press 2 to Deposit");
                System.out.println("Press 3 to Check Amount");
                String operation = question.next();
                switch(operation) {
                    case "1":
                        System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("How much would like to deposit?");
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.out.println("Here is your total amount in your bank");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Press 4 to exit");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My question is how do I store an amount for my users in their ATM? I have tried to add another parameter in the hashmap, but it can only accept 2 parameters.

Comment: You can't. A map is a collection of key/value pairs. One value per key. The common approach is to define a class and store instances of that class as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple values corresponding to a single key. What you can however do is have a nested Hashmap. In that map you can have further user details , such as user name , user address , user balance and so on.

```
Map<String, HashMap<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("123456789" , new HashMap<>());
    map.put("987654321" , new HashMap<>());
    map.get("123456789").put("pin number" , "123456");
    map.get("123456789").put("phone number" , "0000000000");
    map.get("123456789").put("name" , "xyz");
    map.get("123456789").put("balance" , "20000");
    map.get("987654321").put("pin number" , "654321");
    map.get("987654321").put("phone number" , "1111111111");
    map.get("987654321").put("name" , "zyx");
    map.get("987654321").put("balance" , "10000");
```

So the map looks like this ->

{123456789 = { pin number = 123456, balance = 20000 , name = xyz , phone number = 0000000000} , 987654321 = { pin number = 654321 , balance = 10000 , name = zyx, phone number = 1111111111}}

Now for each account number you can store multiple types of values.
To get values corresponding to account number use,

```
 String actualPin = map.get(card).get("pin number");
```

**map.get(card)** will return you the map corresponding to that card account number. And inside that map you can get all of the values you want via the String keys inside that map.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to change the balance to an integer? String total = map.get(card).get("balance");. In this case I will get a String. I tried adding(int) in front of the total when I'm doing if statement but could not.

Comment: Answering to my own comments. String total = map.get(card).get("balance");
                int BalanceInInteger = Integer.parseInt(total); This will change the string values to integer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create another class:

```
class Account {
   private String accountNumber;
   private String pin;
   private String accountOwner;
   private long balance;
```

and so on.   [1]

So, you could  have a `Map <String, Account>` .

```
Account account = map.get(card);
String accountNum = account.getNum ();
String pin = account.getPin ();
```

[1] The number on the card would not normally be the same as the account number. That way, if the card is stolen, the card can be canceled without changing the account number.

Comment: I don't recommend it for this example, but  Java generics allows nesting. You could have a `Collection` of a `Collection`:  `Map <String, List<String>> map = new HashMap <String, ArrayList<String>> ();`

Comment: In principle, one of the reasons we have `class`es is to glue together different related fields so they can be used and manipulated as a unit. I object-oriented languages, we have the additional advantage that we can include methods in a `class`.